# Installing error for Jetty in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, runjettyrun

I have followed some tutorials for Jetty installation for eclipse.

1. In Eclipse go to Help>Install New Software
2. List item Select Add and enter the following:
   Name: Jetty
   Location: http://run-jetty run.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite

I have done all configurations, but still I am getting error while intallations

> Unable to read repository at http:/svn/trunk/updatesite/content.xml.
>
> Unable to read repository at http:/svn/trunk/updatesite/content.xml.
>
> URI does not specify a valid host name:
>
> http:/svn/trunk/updatesite/content.xml

Comment: *What* tutorial is that? Jetty itself isn't a plug-in for the IDE.

Comment: I have used this following  tutorial,https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Installation+for+Developers+On+Windows